# Return an array in php function

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code to retrieve information of user:

```
function getUserProfile($id) {              
            $sql_query_profile="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
            $user_profile=@mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query_profile);
            $user_details_profile=@mysqli_fetch_array($user_profile,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $user_details_profile;
        }
```

when I call this function, it returns null value.

```
$user= getUserProfile($_POST['txt_id']);
    var_dump ($user);
```

can anybody suggest the better idea please?

Comment: So where is `$dbconfig` set in your function? Stop suppressing error messages.

Comment: I've included that at the top of the file as 
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'kathforum';
$dbconfig = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database) or die("An Error occured when connecting to the database");
?>

Comment: function is a different scope, and in this function scope, there is no $dbconfig.

Comment: Do not use `@` handle your errors instead of suppressing them, debugging is impossible when using `@` and we will be unable to help you until you correct this.

Comment: use `global` keyword with `$dbconfig` or pass it to function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to access `$dbconfig` in function which is global variable. To access global variables use `global` keyword in function or pass config variable to function itself.

```
function getUserProfile($id) {  
            global $dbconfig;            
            $sql_query_profile="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
            $user_profile=@mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query_profile);
            $user_details_profile=@mysqli_fetch_array($user_profile,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $user_details_profile;
        }
```

don't use '@' handle as @Epodax suggest, Do not use @ handle your errors instead of suppressing them, debugging is impossible when using @ and we will be unable to help you until you correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access $dbconfig variable please pass through the getUserProfile function arguments .Because $dbconfig may be not retrieve the database connection.so use it following method and same time remove it @ symbol.

```
        function getUserProfile($id,$dbconfig) { 

        $sql_query_profile="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
        $user_profile=@mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query_profile);
        $user_details_profile=@mysqli_fetch_array($user_profile,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $user_details_profile;
    }
```

OR USE IT global declaration for config in main.
 global $dbconfig;    after that call the function.

Comment: Yeah, I declared $dbconfig as global and it solved my problem. Thanks